# Customize Json Response

Tags: json, format, response, jqvmap

I'm trying to implement jqvmap to my project.
My json response in original like;

```
[

{
    "Count": 10,
    "ProvinceCode": 34
},
{
    "Count": 6,
    "ProvinceCode": 59
}
```

The format below, guess only format that jqvmaps accepts.

```
var sample_data = {"34":"10","59":"6"};
```

I've tried some other methods to create response like that but not any success. Any way to create response like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this it will work :**

```
var newObj = {};
var obj = [{
    "Count": 10,
    "ProvinceCode": 34
}, {
    "Count": 6,
    "ProvinceCode": 59
}];

for (var item in obj) {
var keys = obj[item].ProvinceCode;
var values = obj[item].Count;
newObj[keys] = values;
}

console.log(newObj);
```

Working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/s3x2ngdv/

**Output :**

[image]